# integration testing for entity framework to ensure associations are correct

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, integration-testing

I guess this is more of an integration test, but does anyone have a link to a good tutorial on how to test to ensure the associations in your entity framework (4) model are working as expected?

My thought was to use something like sqllite for this, because I want to make sure I can save an entity, and add a child entity and persist that also etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code first, you could use a mocking framework to test your implementation.

As for the IDbSet instances that you can use there, the following was usefull:

```
public class InMemoryDbSet<T> : IDbSet<T> where T : class
{      
    private readonly HashSet<T> _data;
    private readonly IQueryable _query;

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get
        {
            return this._query.ElementType;
        }
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get
        {
            return this._query.Expression;
        }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get
        {
            return this._query.Provider;
        }
    }

    public InMemoryDbSet()
    {
        this._data = new HashSet<T>();
        this._query = _data.AsQueryable();
    }


    public T Add(T entity)
    {
        this._data.Add(entity);
        return entity;
    }


    public T Attach(T entity)
    {
        this._data.Add(entity);
        return entity;
    }


    public TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>() where TDerivedEntity : class, T
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T Create()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public virtual T Find(params Object[] keyValues)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Derive from FakeDbSet and override Find");
    }


    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T> Local
    {
        get
        {
            return new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>(_data);
        }
    }


    public T Remove(T entity)
    {
        this._data.Remove(entity);
        return entity;
    }


    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._data.GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```

Using that approach should enable you to run your test completely in memory without the need to hit a database, but, as i said, only in code first because as far as i know, IDbContext is only used there.

Comment: You could mock the DbSets, but then you are only testing Linq2Objects and not Linq2Sql. Which won't ever execute SQL, thus leaving the database access untested.